# Regexp expression from Oracle SQL to Big Query

Tags: regex, oracle, google-bigquery, sqlhelper

I previously had help here for an Regexp expression in oracle sql which worked great.However, our place is converting to Big Query and the regexp does not seem to be working anymore.

In my tables, i have the following data

```
WC 12/10 change FC from 24 to 32
W/C 12/10 change fc from 401 to 340
W/C12/10 18-26
```

This oracle sql would have split the table up to give me the before number (24) and (32) and (12/10).

```sql
cast(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Line_Comment, '((\d+ |\d+)(change )?(- |-|to |to|too|too )(\d+))', 1, 1, 'i',2) as Int) as Before,
cast(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Line_Comment, '((\d+ |\d+)(change )?(- |-|to |to|too|too )(\d+))', 1, 1, 'i', 5) as Int) as After,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(Line_Comment, '((\d+)(\/|-|.| )(\d+)(\/|-|.| )(\d+))|(\d+)(\/|-|.| )(\d+)', 1, 1, 'i') as WC_Date,
```

Totally understand that comments are not consistent and may not work but if it works more than 80% of the time which it has then we are fine with this.

Since moving to big query, I'm getting this error message. In oracle, the tables were in **varchar** but in big query when they migrated it, its now in **strings**. Could this be the reason why its broken?Is there anyone who can help with this?This is way over my head.

> No matching signature for function REGEXP_SUBSTR for argument types:
> STRING, STRING, INT64, INT64, STRING, INT64. Supported signatures:
> REGEXP_SUBSTR(STRING, STRING, [INT64], [INT64]); REGEXP_SUBSTR(BYTES,
> BYTES, [INT64], [INT64]) at [69:12]

Comment: i suggest you to just present sample of your input data, desired output and logic - so we will be able to better help you!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant hi there, this is what i would like to see. Thanking you in advance. https://i.postimg.cc/527Qgg33/SQl.png

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

Since google bigquery [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_substr) doesn't support the `subexpr` parameter of Oracle's [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html), you need to modify your regexes to take advantage of the fact that:

> If the regular expression contains a capturing group, the function returns the substring that is matched by that capturing group.

So for each value you are trying to extract, you need to make that the only capturing group in the regex:

```sql
cast(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Line_Comment, '(?:(\d+ |\d+)(?:change )?(?:- |-|to |to|too|too )(?:\d+))', 1, 1) as Int) as Before,
cast(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Line_Comment, '(?:(?:\d+ |\d+)(?:change )?(?:- |-|to |to|too|too )(\d+))', 1, 1) as Int) as After,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(Line_Comment, '((?:\d+)(?:\/|-|.| )(?:\d+)(?:\/|-|.| )(?:\d+))|((?:\d+)(?:\/|-|.| )(?:\d+))', 1, 1) as WC_Date,
```

Note you can substantially simplify your regexes as below:

```
(\d+) ?(?:change )?(?:-|too?) ?(?:\d+)
(?:\d+) ?(?:change )?(?:-|too?) ?(\d+)
(?:\d+)(?:[\/.-](?:\d+)){1,2}
```

Regex demos on regex101: [numbers](https://regex101.com/r/qfQkjh/1), [date](https://regex101.com/r/oRSS3B/1)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data you provided in the comment section, you can try below query:

```sql
with t1 as (
  select 'WC 12/10 change FC from 24 to 32' as Comment
  union all select 'W/C 12/10 change fc from 401 to 340' as Comment,
  union all select 'W/C12/10 18-26' as Comment
)

select Comment,
regexp_extract(t1.Comment, r'(\d+\/\d+)') as WC,
regexp_extract(t1.Comment, r'.+\s(\d{1,3})[\s|\-]') as Before,
regexp_extract(t1.Comment, r'.+[\sto\s|\-](\d{1,3})$') as After
from t1
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider below super simple approach

```
select Comment, 
  format('%s/%s', arr[offset(0)], arr[safe_offset(1)]) as wc,
  arr[safe_offset(2)] as before,
  arr[safe_offset(3)] as after
from your_table, unnest([struct(regexp_extract_all(Comment, r'\d+') as arr)])
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]